# Could not find package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package phpspreadsheet.

  Did you mean one of these?
      portphp/spreadsheet
      phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
      ideea/excel
      phpoffice/phpexcel
      codeplex/phpexcel
```

I was follow the instruction, from :

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

but this code show.

Do I forget something?

Comment: Probably worth showing your code here too.  From first glance it looks like the phpoffice/ is missing as phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is in the list and the error says the package you have asked for is just phpspreadsheet

Comment: what should I do ? :)

Comment: post your code :)

Comment: I just open Git Bash, and run composer with this :)) =>

$ composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet